# paste a String outside the java app on a Website

Tags: java

My Problem is as follows... I wrote a small Desktop application for managing userdata. Now i am writing a "Log In" function. I found that auto-find Loginfields of any Website would be to difficult for me so i want to do this.

If a user presses on "Log in" my application starts the give website with the system's default browser. Now in the website click on the username field -> the program pastes the username. Now press TAB to jumb over to the password field -> the password gets pasted in automatically by the application.

How can i achieve this, is it even viable/possible. I thought this might do the trick, called first on a mouseclick and then on a TAB... but i am stuck.

```
private void pasteData(String str){
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(str);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I know, that this is not really good answer, but why do you doing this in this way?

I know, that you have desktop app made in Java and you want to communicate with website. Ok. This is possible, but I do not recommend to do it this way (Java `Robot` class). Why? Because you basically can´t know where is webpage login form and where to paste text (login and password), so if you are searching for more effective way, how to do it, there it is:

**1.) JavaScript or browser plug-in**
Most effective way how to communicate with user defeult browser is made simple plug-in and then pass information to this plug-in and back to program. With this plug-in, you can very simple find login form or save passwords automatically.

**2.) Embedded browser in your program**
From [webview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) you can easy get html elements and pass or get information from it.

**or) Your Robot way** 
Your code is right, but please check, that you are on Windows, and not on other OS, that can have another keypress combination for paste. For other users is this way working, so check if you have another code right.

And also try to change `clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);` to `clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);`, because .setContents have in second argument owner:

```
setContents(Transferable contents, ClipboardOwner owner)
```

> Sets the
>   current contents of the clipboard to the specified transferable object
>   and registers the specified clipboard owner as the owner of the new
>   contents.

Comment: Ok thank you, now i know even more that i need to think about a better approach. This helped